# The clear() function does not work on input of type number

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have protractor 2.2.0.

The `clear()` function does not work on input of type number. I have tried most of the solutions given here. Please help me. Below is my code:

```
element(by.model('lineup.voltage_limit')).click().clear().sendKeys(value);
```

I have tried to even resolve the promise from clear() like below

```
element(by.model('lineup.voltage_limit')).click().clear().then(function(){
   element(by.model('lineup.voltage_limit')).sendKeys(value); 
});
```

`clear()` just does not seem to work! It just keeps on appending to the text in the input box.

Comment: can you try remove click()?  element(by.model('lineup.voltage_limit')).clear().then(function(){
   element(by.model('lineup.voltage_limit')).sendKeys(value); 
});

Comment: I have tried even that but it's still getting appended.

Comment: Can you try using `sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE)` and test if it is working instead?

Comment: I have already tried this also but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code of the input you are trying to clear? Or, even better would be to make the example reproducible for us. Thanks.

Comment: browser.executeScript("document.getElementById('voltage').value = '';"); 

This code does not clear the text it inserts 0 instead.
The input box is of type = 'number'

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce the problem using this [demo page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number). Here is [the test](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/afcf1baf754c3265ee7b) I've used.

I suspect your input is somewhat special and has to always have a value. What we can do is to *pre-select the existing text with `CTRL`/`COMMAND` + `A`* so that once you start sending keys, the existing text is replaced by newly inserted:

```
var elm = element(by.model('lineup.voltage_limit'));
elm.click().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "a"));

elm.sendKeys(value);
```

where the `browser.controlKey` is a [way to handle `CTRL` vs `COMMAND` on different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33279539/771848).

---

As a side note, I would also upgrade `Protractor` to the latest (currently 3.0) version which would come with new webdrivers that might handle your problem better.

Comment: upgrading is a great idea! :)

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to get mine to work by calling `clear` twice like this

```
numInput.clear().clear().sendKeys('7');
```

Not sure if this will work for everyone but it worked for me. alexce's answer also looks like a good one.

*edit:* this seems to work only some of the time. i don't know why, maybe my inputs are just weird