# How can I use browser.actions().sendKeys in protractor with "?" symbol?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a trouble in my tests with this code

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, '?')).perform();
```

But it's work with another symbol. For example:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, 'a')).perform();
```

How can I use `browser.actions().sendKeys` in protractor with "?" symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to open the browser's Help->Search, should not it be:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.CONTROL, Key.SHIFT, '/')).perform();
```

Note that I'm not sure if would be able to control the search input and send keys to it, since, I think it might be out of scope of the selenium webdriver.

And FYI, if you would want it be cross-platform, see:

- [Using cross-platform keyboard shortcuts in end-to-end testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263091/using-cross-platform-keyboard-shortcuts-in-end-to-end-testing)