# Text in clipboard with protractor js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, bdd

How can I copy a specific text with protractor ?

I would like to load a text to paste after with this command :

```
return browser.actions().sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v').perform();
```

Sample :

Load my text "test" and after with this command, paste "test"

I would like put a text in my clipboard

Comment: When you say specific text, is that text in a separate element or is it in one element and you are trying to extract it from that? Can you also update your question with the html element code that you are trying to perform operations on? Thanks

Comment: A text in my clipboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can I put a value directly in my ng-model, not use sendKeys ?

Yes, you can directly set the `model` value via [`.evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate):

```
var elm = element(by.model("mymodel.field"));
elm.evaluate("mymodel.field = 'test';");
```

---

### Putting a text into clipboard

The idea is to use an existing or dynamically create an `input` element where you would send the text to, select all the text in the input and copy it with a `CTRL/COMMAND + C` shortcut.

Sample:

```
var textToBeCopied = "my text";

// creating a new input element
browser.executeScript(function () {
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.setAttribute('id', 'customInput'); 

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(el);
});

// set the input value to a desired text
var newInput = $("#customInput");
newInput.sendKeys(textToBeCopied);

// select all and copy
newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "a"));
newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "c"));
```

where `browser.controlKey` is a cross-platform way to handle `CTRL`/`COMMAND` keys:

- [Using cross-platform keyboard shortcuts in end-to-end testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263091/using-cross-platform-keyboard-shortcuts-in-end-to-end-testing)

Comment: Thx ! Also, can I put a value directly in my ng-model, not use sendKeys ?

Comment: Thx ! Just last question : can I push my text with sendKeys instantly, I don't have the tapping effect, it's possible ?

Comment: @JérémieChazelle well, if you are pasting from clipboard with command/ctrl + v, then yes..but with sendKeys I think it would always be one by one. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe 
Performing the paste operation pastes text as "mytext" rather than "my text", I need text with spaces/tab whatever specified in the string.
Also sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "a")); wasn't working for me used newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a"));

Comment: In chrome it removes the spaces/tabs i.e "mytext" rather than "my text" and firefox it only pastes the first part of the string "my"

Comment: It seems that the code does not work on macOS. Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat related to this: I needed to test a dialog, which placed some text in the clipboard when the user pressed the 'Copy' button in the dialog. I wanted to test that the text really got copied to the clipboard. I found this 'copy-paste' library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-paste . "A command line utility that allows read/write (i.e copy/paste) access to the system clipboard. It does this by wrapping pbcopy/pbpaste (for OSX), xclip (for Linux and OpenBSD), and clip (for Windows)." I would say it is a javascript module rather than a command line utility. Anyway, I started using it, as the depenency on xclip (for Linux) was not a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet I use with protractor to copy text to the clipboard. I need tabs to be accepted because most of my testing involves cut-and-paste from spreadsheets, where tab is the default column delimiter.

Further, it accommodates nuances in the html body's layout better (overflow: hidden).

```js
function copyToClipboard(browser, text) {
  var id = 'someCustomIdToAvoidAliasing';
  var newInput = browser.element(by.css("#" + id));
  return browser.executeScript(function () {
    var el = document.createElement('textarea');
    el.setAttribute('id', 'someCustomIdToAvoidAliasing');
    el.setAttribute('style', 'position:fixed;z-index:10000;top:0;left:0');
    el.onkeydown = function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        this.value = this.value + "\t";
        return false;
      }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(el);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return newInput.sendKeys(text);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a", protractor.Key.NULL);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "c", protractor.Key.NULL);
  })
  .then(function() {
    return browser.executeScript(function() {
      var el = document.getElementById('someCustomIdToAvoidAliasing');
      el.remove();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Using ** "Copy-paste" **
'var text = "Copied Text"
require("copy-paste").copy(text);        element(by.id('csv')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "v"));'