# In Protractor and Selenium webdriver, how do you get text that has been copied to the clipboard?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, clipboard, e2e-testing, angular9

We are using Angular 9, webdriver-manager 12.1.7, and protractor 5.4.3.  We are trying to verify in our end-to-end test that a copy button is working.  When the user clicks the button, certain text is copied to the clipboard so that the user can paste it later (using Ctrl +V or Cmd+V, depending on your OS).  We have

```
import { ExpectedConditions as EC, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
...

  async getTextFromClipboard() {
    ...
    await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('.btn-copy'))), waitTimeout);
    await element(by.css('.btn-copy')).click();
```

What I am not sure is how, in protractor, do we then programmatically get the text that has been copied to the clipboard?

Comment: The clipboard's *outside* the browser, you either need to paste into an input or other element or use e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-paste

Comment: We did something like that before I remembered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34877948. So, indeed, this was an extra temporary input to which keys are sent.