# How can I use copy and paste with protractor on MAC with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

How can I use copy and paste with protractor on MAC with Chrome?

```
newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "a"));
newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "c"));
newInput.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "v"));
```

I have "undefined" when I use this code

I use this code from this post [Using cross-platform keyboard shortcuts in end-to-end testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263091/using-cross-platform-keyboard-shortcuts-in-end-to-end-testing) but it doesn't work:

```
browser.controlKey = protractor.Key.CONTROL; //browser.controlKey is     a global variable and can be accessed anywhere in the test specs
browser.getCapabilities().then(function(capabilities){
    if(capabilities.caps_.platform === "MAC")
        browser.controlKey = protractor.Key.COMMAND;
});

elm.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(browser.controlKey, "c"));
```

Comment: this could help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263091/using-cross-platform-keyboard-shortcuts-in-end-to-end-testing

Comment: What browser are you trying to `sendKeys()` to? There is an issue with selenium webdriver for not being able to `sendKeys()` in mac platform.

Comment: My browser is "Chrome"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known `chromedriver` problem](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=30). Unfortunately, sending keyboard shortcuts from Protractor/WebDriverJS is not going to work on Chrome+Mac.

In our project, we've moved all of the tests that involve using keyboard shortcuts to Firefox:

```
var firefox_only_specs = [
    "../specs/sometest1.spec.js",
    "../specs/sometest2.spec.js"
];

exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: "chrome",
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ["incognito", "disable-extensions", "start-maximized"]
            },
            specs: [
                "../specs/*.spec.js"
            ],
            exclude: firefox_only_specs
        },
        {
            browserName: "firefox",
            specs: firefox_only_specs
        }
    ],

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can I change my driver on selenium ?

Comment: @JérémieChazelle just don't use Chrome for these kind of tests (well, or run them on windows on a remote selenium server, like `BrowserStack` for example).

Comment: the feeling I get when I read this and I know that the project I'm testing doesn't work on Firefox :C

Answer (score 2):

`protractor.Key.COMMAND` has been tagged as a [wontfix in Protractor's github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/690) for MAC. Here is a solution I adapted from [keyboard commands for left-handed users](https://lifehacker.com/three-keyboard-shortcuts-left-handers-can-actually-use-1548841723)

Universal copy+paste alternative working for MAC, LINUX, and WINDOWS:

```
// This does a select all
element1.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.SHIFT, protractor.Key.HOME));

 // This copies the text
element1.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.INSERT));

// This pastes it in another element
element2.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.SHIFT, protractor.Key.INSERT));
```