# How to Copy Paste a URL From Clipboard and navigate to it using AngularJS Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Iam currently trying to demonstrate a copy paste action using Protracter. I need to copy  a url and open a new tab and paste and navigate to it. Currently I'am able to copy and open a new tab and paste the URL in Address Bar but I'am unable to navigate to the URL in Address Bar.Please find the code below.

```
 browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "t")).perform();
  browser.sleep(2000);
  browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function(){
        //do your stuff on the pop up window
  browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'v')).perform();
  browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.ENTER)).perform();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925057/how-can-i-use-copy-and-paste-with-protractor-on-mac-with-chrome

Comment: @Emna. I'am using Linux not MAC. I think that thread gives a solution for MAC.

Comment: Sorry for that i think you are on MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser's address bar is out of Protractor/WebDriverJS/Selenium's scope, you cannot control it. But, what you can do is to issue `browser.get()` once you've switched to the newly opened window:

```
browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function() {
  browser.get(url);
});
```

Now, if you don't know the `url` and it's being dynamically retrieved and "sits" in the clipboard, what you can do is to create an `input` element dynamically, paste the contents of the clipboard into the element, and retrieve it via `getAttribute("value")`, see the actual sample implementation here:

- [Text in clipboard with protractor js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875616/text-in-clipboard-with-protractor-js)